# How to evaluate two tables column cell values?

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

customerTable:

```
| customerID | name | address |
```

receiptTable

```
| receiptID | customerNumber | products |
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT customerID, customerNumber 
FROM customerTable, receiptTable 
WHERE customerID != customerNumber
```

What I'm trying to do is get rows of customerID's only if it's not in the receipt table, I really don't even know how to ask this. I apologize.

Comment: Do you want to select the customers who don't have a receipt on the receipt-table? Like the customers who have not bought anything yet?

Comment: @Behrouz exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT customerID, customerNumber 
FROM customerTable 
     LEFT JOIN receiptTable  ON customerID = customerNumber
WHERE customerNumber is NULL
```